# How to get a standalone backtick on German keyboard in Visual Studio Code

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-code, markdown, editing

On a German keyboard layout, `backtick + vowel` gives you an accented character, e.g. `backtick + a` gives `à`. However, `ctrl + backtick` gives you a stand-alone backtick, e.g. `ctrl + backtick + a` gives

```
`a
```

This is obviously very useful for editing Markdown.

Here comes the problem: in Visual Studio Code `ctrl + backtick` is a keybinding for toggling the internal terminal. If I remove this keybinding in `keybindings.json`, the keybinding is gone but `ctrl + backtick` now gives nothing.

```
{   "key": "ctrl+shift+[Equal]"   }
```

Question: how do I configure VSC to give me a standalone backtick on `ctrl + backtick`?

Comment: If, by chance you using a linux system, look for `nodeadkeys` keyboard variant options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should bind your chosen key combination to write a single backtick:

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+[Equal]",

    "command": "type",
    "args": {"text":"`"},

    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
 },
```